# how to stop a button from overruling a drag gesture

Tags: ios, uibutton, uiimage, uigesturerecognizer

I have an image that can be dragged on the screen along the y axis and it works brilliantly, but when when I place a button on top of the image which tracks the image (moves with the image, so it's always on top), when trying to drag the button (as it's on top of the image I want to drag), the image won't budge. The button is just cancelling out the drag gesture. How do I prevent this from happening while still enabling the user to press the button? I'm using a UIPanGestureRecognizer

I've tried various ways but they don't work. Go steady with me please, I've very new to developing and this is my first App Store app :)

Thanks

Comment: So the UIButton is on the UIImage and when you drag the image touching the image it works but when you drag the image touching the button it does not work?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I am not sure if these will solve your issue but you can try both of them and see which one works.

1) Make the UIButton a subview of the UIImage so that it inherits the gesture recognizer.

2) Add a pan gesture recognizer to the UIButton with the same handler as the image.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. Could you tell me how to make the UIButton a subview of the UIImage? I'm unsure on topics of subviews.

Comment: You can do it in the storyboard by pressing the view and then the "show document outline button" in the lower left hand corner (circle with a box and left pointing arrow).  The views are presented like a file system and you can drag one into another one representing subclassing.  The alternative is if you have the button and uiimage represented as properties/objects in your header or private @interface you can in viewDidLoad add the line [self.yourImageViewName addSubview: self.yourButtonViewName] where the values with your are what you decided to call them in your file.

Comment: Thanks again for your reply. I attempted this but it didn't have the desired effect. The button still can't be dragged and it can't be pressed either! I had to use the "coded" way to do it too since I wasn't able to do what you instructed regarding dragging the button into the image. It may be because both are in a scrollview (I put them there). I don't know. I take it they are a subview of the scrollview then, right? Anyway, meanwhile, I'll try your second suggestion. However if you think I've done something wrong in the meantime, I would appreciate it if you point it out to me :)

Comment: Right, I did your second suggestion and all works. Thanks so much for your help! :) And I now understand what a subview is and that I use it all the time already!